# How to Add Meta Tags For Each Post Separately in Blogger?

Tags: seo, keyword, meta-tags, blogger, meta

I have just Started With Blogging and Created My New Blog [I'M FROSTY](http://www.imfrosty.com) with Blogger. As I'm asking my question here, I already know, We need to Add Following Code to "Custom HTML Template Editor" in Header Part to add "Meta Tags" for each post for SEO.

```
<!--
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "PAGE-URL"'>
<meta content='PAGE-DESCRIPTION' name='description'/>
<meta content='PAGE-KEYWORDS' name='keywords'/></b:if>
-->
```

I have also Googled for solution but there are replicas of this same answer. But this is practically impossible to add this code for each post if we have 1000's of posts. That template will becomes heavy and difficult to manage. so **Can we do this with any other easier way ?** or **Can We Add "Add Meta Tags" Widget to Post Editor that work similarly like "Add Search Description" or "Add Lables" widgets in right column of post editor ?**
- Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do. You can only set the meta description from the post editor. But to set the keyword, it will be a bit tricky. You can use the post title as keyword with some repetition.

By the way, using `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "PAGE-URL"'>` conditional tag is not a wise action. You will spend about 1 month to manually set the `description` and `keyword` for 1000 posts.

Simply use a bit code, set the description from post editor, and then use title repetition as keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not there as of date.

Go to the official blogger product forums and post your suggestion in the suggestions forum.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/blogger/feature-suggestions--feedback

They do go through our suggestion and respond/implement our suggestions sooner or later.